# I'm getting NaN in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

*I'm getting problems trying to calculate a total value that is a sum of a multiplication result 
and the current value of the total. I'm working with inputs and I dont know what I am missing.*

```
var monto = parseInt(cantidad.value) * parseInt(precio.value);
            var total = document.getElementById("total");
            var t = 0;
            var num1 = monto;
            var num2 = total.value;

            t = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);

            total.value = t;
```

Comment: what are the form field values?

Comment: Maybe you can solve your own issue by outputting the values after you set them to know which field could be causing the issue.

Comment: Try `console.log(num1, num2)` and tell us what it says

Comment: Need to know the values of `cantidad.value` and `precio.value`

Comment: the line that goes  before the sum was a mistake

Comment: Cantidad.value =1 and Precio.value=10

Comment: HUH: `t = total.value; total.value = t;` makes zero sense

Comment: i know  this part is a error, sorry

Answer (score 2):

tldr; This is caused because [`parseInt(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) over one or more of inputs results in NaN. This occurs when the input does not represent a valid number, like `parseInt("foo")` or `parseInt(undefined)`.

This introduces a silent NaN which will "contaminate" the math operations: `NaN + x -> NaN` or `x + NaN -> NaN`.

While [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) can be used as a guard, the "correct" approach would likely be to find out *which* `parseInt` results in NaN (and for *which* input) and fix that. The [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) keyword can be useful here which, when used with the appropriate developer tools, allows the situation (i.e. specific values) to be analyzed.